# EMR Spark - TransportClient: Failed to send RPC

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr

I'm getting this error, I tried to increase memory on cluster instances and in the executor and driver parameters without success.

```
17/05/07 23:17:07 ERROR TransportClient: Failed to send RPC 6465703946954088562 to ip-172-30-12-164.eu-central-1.compute.internal/172.30.12.164:34706: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

Does anyone have any clue to fix this error?

BTW I'm using YARN as cluster manager

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally I resolved the problem. It was due to insufficient disk space. One column of hadoop logs showed:

Hadoop YARN: 1/1 local-dirs are bad: /var/lib/hadoop-yarn/cache/yarn/nm-local-dir; 1/1 log-dirs are bad: /var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers

Googling it I found http://gethue.com/hadoop-yarn-11-local-dirs-are-bad-varlibhadoop-yarncacheyarnnm-local-dir-11-log-dirs-are-bad-varloghadoop-yarncontainers/

> "If you are getting this error, make some disk space!"

To see this error I have to activate the yarn logs in EMR. See

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-web-interfaces.html

To have access to the logs port in the cluster ec2 instances I changed security groups for it

i.e.:

> master instance was listening here: 172.30.12.84:8088 And core
>   instance here: 172.30.12.21:8042

Finally I fixed the problem changing in etl.py the type of instances by other ones with bigger disks:

> master: m3.2xlarge
>   core: c3.4xlarge

Answer (score 5):

When I setup hadoop and spark in my laptop and try to launch spark as "spark-shell --master yarn" I got the same error message.

Solution:

> sudo vim /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml

Add the following property:

```
<property>       
<name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>      
<value>5</value>  
</property>
```

Then restart hadoop service

```
stop-all.sh 
start-all.sh
```

Comment: This made my life easy :) Thanks a ton